# Navigating between ListFragment and Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

My school assignment has an activity that contains a ListFragment and a Fragment. The MainActivity creates the ListFragment, and then each item on the list should open the regular Fragment that just contains a picture, and then when I click on the picture it should go back to the ListFragment.

In all cases, I call the fragments using this code (edited for the specific case of course):

```
    Fragment fragTwo = new FragmentTwo();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragTwo);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

It calls the fragments OK, except that the second fragment will appear OVER the ListFragment, and I can still select things from the list while the second fragment is open. Do I need to create a new fragment object every time I navigate? And how do I disable/enable a fragment from it's own onclick listener?

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.w0068332.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How is the activity inserting the ListFragment? Is it in the activity's layout xml, or are you adding it programmatically with a FragmentTransaction? It may help to post your activity and xml layout code.

Comment: @Benstrom I've added main_activity.xml, as you can see there is a fragment item that the fragments are placed into. In onCreate of mainActivity I use (essentially) the first piece of code to put the fragment (fragOne) into place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Yes you need to create a fragment for each item.

```
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putInt(FragmentTwo.ARG_ITEM_ID,R.drawable_pic);
                    FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
```

I suppose that you display pictures from resources

2- To disable selection from ListFragment while displaying the second one.
In the parent layout of the second fragment you have to add background and make it clickable as below:

```
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
```

3- To navigate back for the ListFragment add a click listener for the ImageView and onClick call onBackPressed of the Activity:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

you can also have a look on a template from Android studio for Master and details activity
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The part I really needed was the getActivity().onBackPressed();. I think it was because I was putting a second instance of the first fragment on top and constantly building new fragments.